# parsing proc/pid/cmdline to get function parameters

Tags: c++, linux, procfs

I'm trying to extract the parameter with which an app was called by using the data inside cmdline.

If I start an application instance like this:

> myapp 1 2

and then cat the cmdline of myapp I will see something like myapp12.

I needed to extract these values and I used this piece of code to do it

---

```
pid_t proc_id = getpid();

sprintf(buf,"/proc/%i/cmdline",proc_id);

FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen (buf,"r");
if (pFile!=NULL)
{
    fread(buf,100,100,pFile);
    cout << "PID " << proc_id << endl;
    string str = buf;
    cout << buf << endl;
    size_t found=str.find_last_of("/\\");
    cout << " file: " << str.substr(found+1) << endl;

    fclose (pFile);
}
```

---

But what I am getting is only the app name and no parameters...

---

Update coppied from answer:

well, my question now seems to be how do I read the cmdline file without it stopping at the first NULL character...

```
fopen(cmdline, "rb")
```

doesn't do anything else so...

Comment: After fighting this today, I wanted to note that I had to use: `fread(buf,1,100,pFile);` (size=1, count=buffer length).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of the command line parameters (what would come through as the `argv[]` array) are actually null-separated strings in `/proc/XXX/cmdline`.

```
abatkin@penguin:~> hexdump -C /proc/28460/cmdline
00000000  70 65 72 6c 00 2d 65 00  31 20 77 68 69 6c 65 20  |perl.-e.1 while |
00000010  74 72 75 65 00                                    |true.|
```

This explains why when you `cat`'ed `cmdline` they were all "stuck" together (`cat` ignored the invalid NULL characters) and why your `cout` stopped after the first command line argument (the process name) since it thought that the process name was a null-terminated string and stopped looking for more characters at that point.

**Processing Command Line Arguments**

To process the command line arguments, you have a couple options. If you just want the entire command line as one giant string, loop from the 0 to `(numRead - 2)` (where `numRead` is the number of characters read) and replace any NULL bytes `(curByte == 0)` with spaces. Then just make sure to set the last character to be a NULL byte too (in case things got truncated due to the fixed-size buffer).

If you instead want an array with all of the arguments, you need to be more creative. One option would be to loop from 0 to `(numRead - 1)` and could all of the NULL bytes that you find. Then allocate an array of `char*`'s of that length. Then loop back through the command line, setting the beginning of every string (i.e. the first byte in the array, plus each byte following a NULL byte) to consecutive elements of the array of `char*`'s.

Just know that since you read to a fixed-size buffer, anything beyond that buffer would be truncated. So remember that whatever you do, you probably need to manually make sure that the end of the last string ends up being NULL terminated, otherwise most string handling functions won't know where the string ends and will keep on going forever.

Comment: I saw that already ;)

The problem with read or fread is that they stop at the first NULL and don't get the rest of the parameters...

how do I get around this?

Cheers

Comment: `read` and `fread` don't stop, it is the `cout` (or possibly the `string` construction from the buffer, not sure) that stop. Check the return value from your `fread` and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Adam, this is my thanks to you for your help.

I was getting the programmers syndrome and wanted to destroy the escape key ;).

Your suggestion was spot on. Once again, thanks ;)

Answer (score 9):

`/usr/bin/strings /proc/1337/cmdline` usually do the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Many files supplied in |path| have incorrect size (proc files etc). Hence, the file is read sequentially as opposed to a one-shot read.

```cpp
std::string cmdline;
char buf[1024];
size_t len;
FILE *fp = fopen("/proc/self/cmdline", "rb");
if (fp) {                       
    while ((len = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp)) > 0) {
        cmdline.append(buf, len); // note: `len` here is very important
    }
}
```

Then, you get the whole command line also the parameters. But the reason you can only get the app name or the file path and no parameters when you try to print it is the command line you've got is separated with `'\0'`, something like `"./exefile_name\0-param1=p1\0-param2=p2"`. So you can only get the part that ahead the first `'\0'`, because the machine assumes that the string is end at that place. You also need to tokenize it with `'\0'` first, then try to print it or use it.

```cpp
std::stringstream tokens(cmdline);
std::string tmp;
while (getline(tokens, tmp, '\0')){
    std::cout << tmp << std::endl;
}
fclose(fp);
```